# Sonarqube MaxPermSize error

Tags: sonarqube

Sonarqube software of department, demo and learning.
StartSonar.bat does not start.

Error Log below:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
```

I’m studied the error:

```
Jira task number:SONAR-5204  this jira status:closed  and resolution:fixed will set.
```

MaxPermSize line in wrapper.conf was romeved.

[wrapper.config and sonar.log files click.](https://gist.github.com/serdarkaracay)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run SonarQube with a JDK 8, which is not supported (yet). Please revert to a previous version (JDK 7 is perfectly suitable).

Comment: And indeed ticket https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5204 has been fixed in version 4.3 which was released on Friday.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the same error; However, the problem was not about Java version. As I went and looked into the logs, it was found that I copied new version of FindBug library and there was a conflict as two FindBug library existed. Thus, it may be good idea to look into sonar.log file which could be found in *sonar_install_directory/logs* folder.